# How to sum a list of numbers in vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a vba function in my Word macro that returns a comma separated list of numbers as a string. For example;

```
var = (1.5, 2, 3, 5)
```

How  would I add them up to find the sum?

Comment: You need to split the string into a string array, convert each substring into a number using `Val`, `CDbl`, or `CSng` _(based on your requirements)_ and then add the numbers. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the string into a string array, convert each substring into a number using `Val`, `CDbl`, or `CSng` *(based on your requirements)* and then add the numbers.

Here's an example:

```
Dim inputStr As String
inputStr = "1.5, 2, 3, 5"
Dim arr() As String
arr = Split(inputStr, ",")

Dim total As Single     ' Or `Double` if you need more accuracy.
For Each subStr In arr
    total = total + Val(subStr)     ' Use `Val` if you want to ignore non-numeric values.
    'total = total + CSng(subStr)   ' Use `CSng` to break when finding non-numeric values.
    'total = total + CDbl(subStr)   ' Use `CDbl` if you need more accuracy.
Next

MsgBox total
```

Answer (score 2):

replace `","` with `"+"` and use `Evaluate` formula on string. Note: Have to create reference to Excel instance which is a little heavy handed to say the least! I can't find a word equivalent of Evaluate function which seems a little odd:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim inputStr As String, oXL As Object
    inputStr = "1.5, 2, 3, 5"
    With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    MsgBox .Evaluate(Replace(inputStr, ",", "+"))
       .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like that @QHarr

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for a Word macro, not Excel

Comment: I made a reference to Excel. Little heavy handed I admit!

Comment: @cindymeister - Is there a method in Word for evaluating a string please? Can't seem to find one at present.